# How to handle a JSON with same value names in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, spotify

I have this JSON from spotify API:

[link](https://api.spotify.com/v1/search?q=don%27t%20worry%20be%20happy&type=track&limit=1)

I need to find a way to get the track id, preferably all the ids, but I can't find a way to assign the IDs to variables. I can only get the first one. I have been working on this problem the last 2 days and it's getting too frustrating to find the solution without asking for help.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, if you want help please add the example data and relevant code in the question body and also the desired outcome. Do not link to external sources such as Pastebin or an actual API endpoint as you should not expect people willing to help you to jump though a bunch of hoops and it contributes to link rot.

Comment: The relevant code? You want me to add the GET request? Because beyond that there isn't other than search = json.parse search2 = search['tracks']['items'] The problem is specifically that I can't use this method because when a hash has the same keys it will return an integer, or I can use other methods to get only values or the first id key and value. I didin't include any code because i'm willing to accept any useful information. I didin't include the GET request because I didin't think it was relevant. I included the link instead of pasting because I didin't want to delete the links inside it

Comment: YES, http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I also did not ask for or do I want a ready code that I can just copy paste. The post says that I need to find a way, pointing to that I'm looking for information that is helpful in my problem.

Answer (score 1):

First, read some Ruby related books.

Second, here is an example solution since you've been stuck for 2 days. You have to be rewarded for your persistence! :)

```
# Assume you have that result in text format in `result` variable
# It means that we need to parse it and turn it into ruby hash
result =<<RESULT
  "tracks" : {
    "href" : "https://api.spotify.com/v1/search?query=don%27t+worry+be+happy&offset=0&limit=1&type=track","
...
RESULT


# Let's parse it using JSON gem
require 'json'
json = JSON.parse(result)

### If your result is already parsed into Ruby hash, then skip the above code.

unless json.dig('tracks', 'items').empty?
  json['tracks']['items'].map {|i| i['id'] }
end

# This will return an array of all track id's
 => ["4v52HuhZqVV0eNpP6vzH5I"]
```